# Getting undefined value from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, undefined

I´m getting undefined on my website from the "Bestillinger" child from firebase, and I cannot figure out why.
All the other returns is working fine.

Here is the code:

```js
var ref = database.ref("users");
  ref.on("value", gotData, errData);

  function gotData(data) {
   // console.log(data.val);
   var users = data.val();
   var keys = Object.keys(users);
   //console.log(keys);

   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys [i];
    var adresse = users [k].Adresse;
    var navn = users [k].Navn;
    var postnr = users [k].Postnummer;
    var telefon = users [k].Telefon;
    var bestilling = users [k].Bestilling;

    document.getElementById('BB').innerHTML = navn + adresse +  postnr + telefon + bestilling;
    console.log(adresse,navn,postnr,telefon,bestilling);
```

And here is how Firebase looks like:

[image: Firebase]

And, I´m also wondering how the website can be updated every time someone updates/changes the "Bestillinger" (orders)
I want all information on the user to be presented when he/she makes an order.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Looking at the DB image, there are two colons (:) after `Bestilling`.  Is a colon somehow getting appended to the end of your key?  Maybe a typo in your code?

Comment: You are right! Cant believe I missed that. I looked for typos over and over ^^. Thank you. Do you happen to have a solution for my second problem aswell? I want the data of the customer to be presented in a list, and pushed down the list every time a new order comes in (Bestilling child is changed in firebase)